# How to check the StatusCode in json object to get a string of httpResponse rest API

Tags: c#, web

I can't check StatusCode when REST API and parse JObject

**code**

```
string jsonResponse = HttpRequest(HostAPI, "POST", paramModel);
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
if (jsonObject["data"] != null && jsonObject["StatusCode"]==200)  ????
```

**jsonResponse**

```
{"data":[{"OBJID":1012540462,"SUPID":1041252952,"STATUSPTC":1.0,"DATEACTIVESUP":0.0}],"StatusCode":200}
```

I can not check StatusCode

```
if (jsonObject["StatusCode"]== 200) 
{
   //do something
}
```

Please help me if you know ???

Comment: you can convert json to C# class here http://json2csharp.com/ deserialize it, and check code

Comment: How about jsonObject["StatusCode"]

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: tks all ! I can not check StatusCode, I have modified the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsonObject["StatusCode"] type is **Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue**

So we have to explicitly cast it.

```
 if ((int)jsonObject["StatusCode"] == 200)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("working");
        }
```

You can find [working sample here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0NIqjJ)